# check if dynamically inserted input field exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that adds a button that will open up a window that allows us to design t shirts. All i have top do is include their script and the button gets automatically added.

Below is the code which is dynamically added to the page.

```
<input id="design_edit_btn" class=" btn btn-success btn-block" value="Edit the design" type="button">
```

What i need to do is that, if that button is available then show a message saying its customizable or else display cannot be customized.

I tried the below code

```
if($("#design_edit_btn").length) {

alert("exists");
}
```

I did a bit of research but couldn't find a way to achieve this. Can someone please let me know how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: when is the condition if check made?

Comment: on `$(document).ready() `

Comment: Is the external script loading after your check?

Comment: @lumio i have added the code after the <script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to wait until the script has been loaded and executed.

Try waiting when the document is finished and do something like this:

```js
jQuery(($) => {
  if($("#design_edit_btn").length) {
    alert("exists");
  }
} );
```

jQuery triggers a given callback as soon as the document is ready. If that doesn't work either you could try adding a `setTimeout` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `button` you look for is create by an external script, that script is likely not finished by the time the DOM is ready, hence you won't find it, not even at `$(document).ready()`

What you can try is to use the script tag's `onload`, and when it fires, check for the `button`, like I do here, fire a `console.log` when jQuery have loaded.

*Note, the order of the script is important*

Stack snippet

```html
<script>
function checkForjQuery() {

  console.log('jQuery loaded');

}

function checkForButton() {

  if ($("#design_edit_btn").length) {
    alert("exists");
  }
}
</script>

<script  onload="checkForjQuery()" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--  temp. commented out
<script  onload="checkForButton()" src="your_script_path"></script>
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('design_edit_btn') != null)
{
     alert("exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
if ($("#design_edit_btn").length > 0) {
  alert("exists");
}
```